# Solving complicated linear system

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, linear-algebra, warning-messages, system

I have this system
[image]

and I would solve it with mathematica, I try with the instruction Solve but I have an error
[image]

Please help me.

Comment: How does `In[32]:=` appear twice? The `$RecursionLimit` has been exceeded as you are referring to `In[32]` in that very cell.

Comment: I did not finf another method to solve the system so I try Solve[In]

Comment: I think that the point @Syed is trying to make is that since you used `Solve[In[32]]` the input for `Solve` should be `33` and not `32` again.

Comment: @bmf before the Solve[In] I had an error it's said : more input is needed but I put all the input I don't know the correct way for solving the problem

Comment: Please provide the actual Mathematica code (not a picture of it) you used in your attempt to solve this problem.  Without that information there is little that readers can do to help you.

Comment: Please include all your definitions as text, not pictures. See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951)

Comment: My first comment was referring to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq2CB.png) as well as the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that seems to work.  This approach uses an `Indexed` variable name $a_{m k+1}$ instead of $A_{m k}$, since zero is not a legal index in *Mathematica*.

Start with the smallest possible example and your first equation

```
L = 4; n = 2;
eqn1 = Sum[Indexed[a, {m, k + 1}], {m, 1, n}] == -1;
```

We can define the two $\Pi$-products separately, to make the second equation more readable.

```
p1 = Product[(k + 2 m - s) (k + 2 m + s + 2 λ), {s, 0, q - 1}]
p2 = Product[(k - s) (k + 2 + 2 λ), {s, 0, q - 1}]

eqn2 = Sum[p1 Indexed[a, {m, k + 1}], {m, n}] == -p2
```

These equations are valid for a range of values of $k$ and $q$.  All of the equations can be listed like this

```
eqns = Table[{eqn1, eqn2}, {k, 0, L - 2 n}, {q, n - 1}] // Flatten
eqns // TableForm
```

$\begin{array}{c}
 a_{1\, 1}+a_{2\, 1}=-1 \\
 4 (\lambda +1) a_{1\, 1}+8
   (\lambda +2) a_{2\, 1}=0 \\
\end{array}$

Before using `Solve`, extract the (indexed) variable names from the equations `eqns` like this

```
vars = Cases[eqns, Indexed[a, __], ∞] // DeleteDuplicates;
soln = Solve[eqns, vars] // Flatten;
soln // TableForm
```

$\left\{a_{1\, 1}\to -\frac{2
   (\lambda +2)}{\lambda
   +3},a_{2\, 1}\to
   -\frac{-\lambda -1}{\lambda
   +3}\right\}$

Keep in mind that the second subscript of $a$ is one more than the second subscript of $A$, so $a_{11}$ is $A_{10}$ and $a_{21}$ is $A_{20}$.  Try it with other values for $L$ and for $n$.

A couple of things to notice in this example.  It is really easy to enter expressions using InputForm (typing in `Sum` and `Product`) instead of using TraditionalForm, which shows $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$ with subscripts that can be hard to read.  It is also easier to check long expressions that are broken down into parts.  The use of `In[]` and `Out[]` can save typing, but assigning expressions to variables names (like `p1` and `p2`) makes it possible to test and debug each step.

#### Edit

My original `Table` expression for `eqns` in the above code produces some duplicate equations, since `eqn1` depends on subscript $k$ but not on subscript $q$.  The duplicate equations do not seem to be a problem for `Solve`, but they could be a problem for other methods.  An easy fix is to uses `DeleteDuplicates`, but a better way to produce the list of equations without duplicates is

```
eqns = Table[{eqn1, Table[eqn2, {q, n - 1}]}, {k, 0, L - 2 n}] // Flatten;
```